# Recieve data into javascript from entered url to webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that alerts me the with the current .href of the website. However I want to be able to pass a short variable into the webpage when entering the domain name so that I later can use that in js.

For example going to website localhost entering: *localhost/HelloWorld* **should alert** "*HelloWorld*"

Is this possible?

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Get Current URL in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function getURL() {
        alert("The URL of this page is: " + window.location.href);
    }
    </script>

    <button type="button" onclick="getURL();">Get Page URL</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `pathname` property should do it for you. The [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#wikiArticle) object contains all the host and paths in it.

```
<script>
function getURLPath() {
    alert("The URL path of this page is: " + window.location.pathname);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the address is `https://localhost/HelloWorld`, try `window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]`.

`pathname` is the string `/HelloWorld` that comes after the domain `localhost`. Using `split` you can split it into parts (in this case two). The first part will always be an empty string. The second part will be the string `HelloWorld` in this case.

For this to work, the web server has to serve index.html on all paths. That's standard behavior for Node. Otherwise, you will want to edit your web server's configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `localhost/HelloWorld` the server will try to locate the HelloWorld page, which doesn't exist. Instead the correct way to pass a parameter to a page is through a [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search), for instance: `localhost?q=HelloWorld`. You could also redirect `localhost/HelloWorld` to `localhost?q=HelloWorld` using a custom router, depending on your server, for instance using a `.htaccess` file, if using Apache.

You retrieve the parameter using `window.location.search` or converting to URL object and using [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! It worked. Thanks mate!